# Java - Intercambiar filas en una matriz

Tags: java, array

tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el que se muestre una matriz y intercambiar los valores de la primera fila y la cuarta  y enseñarlos, me he quedado totalmente atascada ya que no se muy bien como hacerlo.
he probado a hacer un bucle for, sin mucho exito la verdad, también a intercambiarlos guardando un auxiliar pero solo me da un numero concreto.

Este es el codigo:

```
public class CambioMatriz {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matriz={{1,2,3,4,5,6,8},{2,1,3,4,5,6,7},{2,3,1,4,5,6,7},
            {2,3,4,1,5,6,7},{2,3,1,5,1,6,7}};
    System.out.println("Tu matriz es:");
    ver(matriz);

    System.out.println("\nAhora la cuarta fila y la primera");
    verPrimeraCuarta(matriz);


}

public static void ver(int[][]matriz) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < matriz.length;i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public static void verPrimeraCuarta(int[][]matriz) {
    int i,j = 0,k,l = 0,aux,cuarta = 0, primera = 0,m,n;

    System.out.println("La primera fila de tu matriz es:");
    for (i = 0; i < matriz.length && i<1;i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
            primera = matriz[i][j];
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("La cuarta fila de tu matriz es:");

    for (k = 3; k < matriz.length && k<4;k ++) {
        for (l = 0; l < matriz[k].length; l++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[k][l]);
            cuarta = matriz[k][l];

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("\nLos valores intercambiados son:");
        aux=primera;
        primera = cuarta;
        cuarta=aux;

    System.out.println("El valor de la primera fila ahora es:"+primera);
    System.out.println("El valor de la cuarta fila ahora es:"+cuarta);


}
```

}

Como puedo cambiar los valores de las filas para que se puedan ver correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analicemos esta parte del código:

```
System.out.println("La primera fila de tu matriz es:");
for (i = 0; i < matriz.length && i<1;i ++) {
  for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
         System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
         primera = matriz[i][j];
  }
  System.out.print("\n");
}
```

El bucle principal sólo hará una iteración (cuando `i` sea mayor a 1, el bucle terminará su ejecución). Luego tenemos otro bucle anidado que hará x iteraciones dependiendo de cuantas columnas tenga la matriz; sin embargo, en ningún momento se hace el intercambio de valores entre la fila `1` y `4`. Por ende, la variable `primera` se quedará con el último valor de la séptima columna de la primera fila (en este caso, es el valor `8`).

Sigamos con el siguiente código:

```
for (k = 3; k < matriz.length && k<4;k ++) {
   for (l = 0; l < matriz[k].length; l++) {
       System.out.print(matriz[k][l]);
       cuarta = matriz[k][l];

   }
   System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Si te das cuenta, este código tendrá el mismo problema del anterior algoritmo. La variable `cuarta` se quedará con el último valor (en este caso es el valor de `7`) de la séptima columna con respecto al cuarta fila.

Por último, tenemos este código:

```
System.out.println("\nLos valores intercambiados son:");
aux=primera;
primera = cuarta;
cuarta=aux;

System.out.println("El valor de la primera fila ahora es:"+primera);    
System.out.println("El valor de la cuarta fila ahora es:"+cuarta);
```

Si ya sabemos que la variable `primera` se quedó con el valor de `8` y la variable `cuarta` con el valor de `7`, lo que estás intercambiando son los valores que tenga ambas variables, por esa razón, te imprimirá como resultado:

```
El valor de la primera fila ahora es: 7
El valor de la cuarta fila ahora es:  8
```

Estás casi cerca de la solución, el problema de este código es que solo sirve para intercambiar los valores de las últimas columnas de la primera y cuarta fila.

**¿Cual sería el algoritmo para este problema?**

Imagínate que la primera y cuarta fila tiene los siguientes valores:

```
i = 0 -> 1  2  3  4  5  6  8
         |
         | 
         |
i = 4 -> 2  3  1  5  1  6  7
```

Para poder intercambiar los valores, debo saber primero en que posición están esos valores. En este caso, el número `1` está en la posición `(0,0)` y el número `2` en la posición `(4,0)`. Después de obtener las posiciones, optamos a crear una variable auxiliar donde guardaremos el valor de `1` (de la posición `(0,0)`) en `aux` (es necesario esta variable para no perder el número `1`), después mandamos el valor de `2` hacia la posición `(0,0)` y por último, mandamos el valor que tenga la variable `aux` (que en realidad es el `1`) hacia la posición `(4,0)`.

En código, lo logramos de esta forma:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program
{
    public static void ver(int[][]matriz) 
    {
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < matriz.length;i ++) 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) 
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void intercambiar(int[][] matriz)
    {
        int aux;
        for(int j = 0; j != matriz[0].length; ++j)
        {
            //Asigna en aux el valor de X columna de la primera fila
            aux = matriz[0][j];
            //Asigna un valor (de la posicion (4,j)) en la posicion (0,j)
            matriz[0][j] = matriz[4][j];
            //Asigna un valor (de aux) en la posicion (4,j)
            matriz[4][j] = aux;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          int[][] matriz=
          {
            {1,2,3,4,5,6,8},
            {2,1,3,4,5,6,7},
            {2,3,1,4,5,6,7},
            {2,3,4,1,5,6,7},
            {2,3,1,5,1,6,7}
        };
        ver(matriz);
        intercambiar(matriz);
        ver(matriz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! muchisimas gracias de nuevo por ayudarme! estoy muy atascada con este tema de los arrays, casi lo tengo pero me esta costando un poco. he estado revisando tu solucion y me ha servido, muchisimas gracias! Ya decía yo que con la forma que lo estaba haciendo era demasiado dificil. He revisado tu solución y al implementarla en mi codigo salía en la quinta fila intercambiado.

Comment: public static void intercambioPrimeraCuarta(int[][]matriz) {
  int aux;
        for(int j = 0; j != matriz[0].length; ++j)
        {      
            aux = matriz[0][j];
            matriz[0][j] = matriz[3][j];
            matriz[3][j] = aux;
        }
        mostrar(matriz);
 }
}
He realizado este cambio y ya sale correcto! Muchisimas gracias!!